# Auto populate dropdown based on previous selection using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am working on Angular 4 reactive forms.Here i have a form with some input fields.Based on one field data, the upcoming field data will be changed.I need to display the countries states and all cities based on previous dropdown selection using angular 4.I tried a lot but i didn't get working solution.Can anyone help me to sort this using this json.

```
{  
"Countries":[  
  { 
    "id":0,
    "CountryName":"Indonesia",
    "States":[  
        {  
           "id":0,
           "StateName":"Bali",
           "Cities":[
                {
                    "id":0,
                    "CityName":"Denpasar",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun1"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun2"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun3"}
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id":1,
                    "CityName":"Kuta",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun4"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun5"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun6"}
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id":2,
                    "CityName":"Tuban",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun7"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun8"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun9"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {  
           "id":1,
           "StateName":"Badgis",
           "Cities":[
                {
                    "id":0,
                    "CityName":"Denpasar",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun1"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun2"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun3"}
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "id":1,
                    "CityName":"Andarab",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun4"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun5"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun6"}
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "CountryName":"India",
    "States":[  
        {  
           "id":0,
           "StateName":"Delhi",
           "Cities":[
                {  
                    "id":0,
                    "CityName":"Sonipat",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun1"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun2"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "CityName":"Rohtak",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun4"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun5"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun6"}
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        },
        {  
           "id":1,
           "StateName":"Karnataka",
           "Cities":[
                {
                    "id":0,
                    "CityName":"Mangalore",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun1"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun2"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "CityName":"Hubli",
                    "Municipalities":[
                        {"id":0,"MunName":"Mun4"},
                        {"id":1,"MunName":"Mun5"},
                        {"id":2,"MunName":"Mun6"}
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi it will be interesting if you post some code you tried ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will more visualized if you share more code snippets.
BTW, you need to add an extra key which tell you about the selected option.

For example
Countries.states[0].cities[2].selected = true

Here you can retrieve the selected key and trace whether it is selected value is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep updating your *ngFor in options based on selection you made in your first dropdown and based on your selection traverse the selected object for next dropdown.

For Reactive form first import formGroup and FormControl in your .ts

```
ind = 0;  // index val of selected drop down
val = 0;
```

and create FormGroup instance

```
  myGroup = new FormGroup({
    CountryName: new FormControl(),
    states: new FormControl(),
    Cities: new FormControl(),
 });
```

and in your HTML simply

```
// data is your json data.

<form  [formGroup]="myGroup">
<select  formControlName="CountryName" (change)="ind = $event.target.value">
  <option *ngFor="let country of data.Countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.CountryName}}</option>
</select>
<select formControlName="states" (change)="val = $event.target.value">
  <option *ngFor="let state of data.Countries[ind].States" [value]="state.id">{{state.StateName}}
  </option>
</select> 
<select formControlName="Cities" (change)="cityVal = $event.target.value">
  <option *ngFor="let Cities of data.Countries[ind].States[val].Cities" 

[value]="Cities.id">{{Cities.CityName}}
      </option>

//......   and so on keep updating your options for all nested array ....
    </select> 

</form >
```